# Does angularjs watch/track property in the scope which are not bound in the html

Tags: angularjs

Does angularjs watch/track the changes of the id property when it is not bound in the html?

**JS**

```
$scope = { firstname: "test1", lastname: "test2", id: 10};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstname" />
<input type="text" ng-model="lastname" />
```

Comment: no it only watches {{}} and property used in ng-model etc and propeties which  are set up manually using scope.$watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does angularjs watch/track the changes of the id property?

Not automatically.  AFAIK, watches are created during the compile phase when angular is parsing through the DOM to understand what it needs to track.  For example, if you define a controller in your module, but never use it with `ng-controller` in HTML, an instance of your controller will never be created.  You can see how this is a good thing.

If you want to manually set up a watch for `id`, then use `$scope.$watch` to do so.

Comment: you have directly answered my question. I did not ask how to watch id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does watch for two-way data-binding. However you should always use the `.`. This is because of prototypal inheritance. The `<form>` tag you've probably used introduced a new child scope and firstname/lastname would be overwritten in that case.

Do not use

```
<input ng-model="firstname"> <!-- NO -->
```

but use

```
<input ng-model="form.firstname"> <!-- YES -->
```

And in your controller, use `$scope.form = { firstname: '...', lastname: '...', id: '...' };`. Angular will watch for changes.

### Watching for `form.id`

You could watch for the change of the `id` property with the following in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('form.id', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      // do something with changed value
});
```